# 2D camera and 3D lidar calibration (kitti format)

Tags: calibration, lidar, kitti

I have camera and lidar calib files like this:

**camera:**
x: 0.8321346282958983
y: -0.011121243238449097
z: -0.5207197332382203

roll: 0.5077840027360132
pitch: 0.7446574568748474
yaw: 0.3340256132006706

width: 1920
height: 1080

cx: 960.0
cy: 540.0
fx: 1881.648438
fy: 1941.380737

distortion: [-0.359138697385788, 0.122108161449432, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

**lidar:**
x: 1.1
y: 0.0
z: 1.84

roll: 0.0
pitch: 0.0
yaw: -0.6

How to make all of the matrix as kitti dataset?

I dont know how to proceed. Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is useful although it is late.
So basically you are given the values for rigid body transformation of the camera w.r.t. body frame of the platform, camera matrix, image size, lens distortion and rigid body transformation of the Lidar w.r.t. body frame of the platform.

For the camera matrix, you take cx,cy, fx,fy and plug it into the 3x3 matrix of the camera, which is
[image: Camera Matrix]

The distortion coefficients are used as is.

The rotation values are given in Euler angles, so you need to convert it into a Rotation matrix. the rotation matrix is calculated as

[image: Rotation matrix]

You can also find a lot of python, C++ libraries to do that. [Here is an example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html)

Lastly your transformation matrix is made up of R|t as shown in
[image]

Just plugin the values of R and T into the 4x4 Identity matrix, to get your transformation matrix.